# Looping through most recent s3 files and pushing them to corresponding tables in Redshift

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I would like to iterate through the latest S3 files and push them to Redshift corresponding tables with the COPY command.

I have a script that reads from Bucket 1 and pushes the CSV files to Bucket 2 on a daily basis.

End path is something like this:

```
dev/prom/mt/table_name/table_name=2020-04-08/table_name_2020-04-08.csv
```

I have a json config file with all the source_table names, target_table_names and columns.

```
tb_list = []
prefix="dev/mt/"
for obj in TARGET_BUCKET.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix):
    if obj.key.endswith(".csv"):
       # print(obj.key)
        path = "s3://bucket-name/" + obj.key

        x = obj.key.replace(prefix, "")
        x = x.split("/")
        RS_TABLE="stg_"+ x[0]     #redshift target table
        S3_OBJECT="/"+ obj.key    #full path to csv file in target bucekt

        ods_list.append("(s3_object: " + S3_OBJECT + "," + RS_TABLE + ")")
```

What would be the fastest and easiest approach? Should I create a dictionary? Will this be one big for loop and the COPY command nested inside?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to load multiple specific files into Amazon Redshift via the `COPY` command, then I would recommend [Using a Manifest to Specify Data Files - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html).

The manifest file contains a list of the objects to load. Then you can run a single `COPY` command that references the manifest file.

However, if you are intending to load each file into a separate table, then it would need a separate `COPY` command for each file (or a separate manifest file for each table being loaded).

Comment: thank you for your reply. Yes, each file will go into a separate table. I managed to get a list [{'rs_table':'table_1', 's3_file':'dev/mt/table_1/table_1=date/table_1_date.csv'},  {'rs_table':'table_2', 's3_file':'dev/mt/table_2/table_2=date/table_2_date.csv'}, {'rs_table':'table_3', 's3_file':'dev/mt/table_2/table_3=date/table_3_date.csv'}]

Comment: You next need to connect to Redshift (eg via psycopg2) and issue the `COPY` commands.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I have a method that i'm pulling from an outside py file, and the connection is working. My question is how to loop through the list above to pass the rs_table and s3_file values?

Answer (score 0):

Your Python code is adding the data as one long string:

```py
ods_list.append("(s3_object: " + S3_OBJECT + "," + RS_TABLE + ")")
```

This does not make it easy to extract the specific fields. It would be better to add a **dictionary** to the list, which can then be extract. For example:

```py
ods_list.append({"s3_object":S3_OBJECT, "table":RS_TABLE})
```

This makes it **a list of dictionaries**.

You can then use a `for` loop to go through the array, extracting the elements:

```py
for object in ods_list:
    some_function(object["s3_object"], object{"table"})
```